# JQuery mobile table column not wrap to Vertical like example

Tags: jquery-mobile

I try to use jQuery mobile table but when I reduce size of browser or open it in my mobile phone column of table not warp to Vertical like example. I copy all code in example it still does not work.

[example](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/tables/docs/tables/movie-list.html)

**This is my import**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-docs.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
```

What did I miss. Please help thanks.

Comment: thank for answer my question.I already found it

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already know that, but it's still worth to mention that **Responsive tables** functionality is part of the unreleased JQM version 1.3. It's not even beta yet. Therefore it might be good enough for exploring and testing but definitely not for production.

That being said, you might need following js and css files:

```
table.js
table.reflow.js
table.columntoggle.js

jquery.mobile.table.css
jquery.mobile.table.reflow.css
jquery.mobile.table.columntoggle.css
```

You can check them out from [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile)

Comment: Well, good for you. If you find an answer to your own question it's always a good idea to post your answer and accept it. This way others can learn from it. On the other hand since you didn't post your answer and if the provided one answers what you asked for you better mark it accepted. Otherwise people will stop answering your questions pretty soon. That's how it works.